# Plugging laptop, Desktop PC, Iphone etc in reverse due to 2 plug pins with same size

Tags: laptop, power-supply, battery, charger

If you have a 2 pin laptop charger and a 2 pin wall outlet and plug in your laptop into the charger and the charger into the outlet upside down due to the 2 pins on the plug having the same dimensions which means the hot pin on the charger goes into the neutral slot and the neutral into the hot slot on the outlet. When this happens does the laptop, PC phone etc receive power in reverse? If not how?

Comment: I am not familiar with any power connector that requires keying not having keyed connectors. If the connector is not keyed, and can therefore be plugged in any direction, then there is no risk of damage any way it is plugged in.

Answer (score 2):

Wall outlets are normally **AC** (Alternating Current) in most places by now. That means the voltage swings positive and negative in a sine wave.

So. It does not matter which way  up you plug the 2-pin plugs in.

Answer (score 2):

> If you have a 2 pin laptop charger and a 2 pin wall outlet

Your wall outlet is AC (Alternating Current) and if just 2 pins, it does not matter which way you put in the plug.

The 2 pin outlets are made so that 2 pin plugs can go in either way without issue.